# How do I create a theme in spree commerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree

I'm using the spree `ruby on rails` ecommerce gem and I have the blue theme installed:

```
 gem 'spree', '0.70.3'
    gem 'spree_blue_theme', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_blue_theme.git', :branch => '0-70-stable'
```

I'd like to customize the theme. For instance changing it from blue to orange.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a github account if you don't have one
2. Go to https://github.com/spree/spree_blue_theme
3. Click the 'Fork' button at the top
4. Clone your fork of the theme, edit away; commit; push
5. Update your gemfile to use your github repo of the theme instead of the official spree one.

As an added bonus, you might want to clone the repo, rename it to your new theme name and then create a new repository for it. But this is for bonus points only.